# XSLT/Java: ERROR: 'Cannot find external method 'max' (must be public).'

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jstl, transform

I am copying an example from [XSLT Cookbook: 2nd Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009748/) (O'Reilly: Mangano, 2006) where Mangano creates a tree diagram with SVG.  As a way to quickly test this code, I am simply transforming the XML using JSTL's `<x:transform/>` tag, and running it in Jetty 6.  The XSLT seems to be getting hung on calling `java:java.lang.Math:max`, saying:

> ERROR:  'Cannot find external method 'max' (must be public).' 
>   FATAL ERROR: 'Could not compile stylesheet'

The code that gives me the error is contained in here where `...Math:max(...` is called:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
                xmlns:emath="http://www.exslt.org/math"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:tree="http://www.ora.com/XSLTCookboox/ns/tree"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
                xmlns:Math="xalan:java.lang.Math">
...
<!--Pass 1 copies input with added bookkeeping attributes -->  
<xsl:variable name="treeWithLayout">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="layout"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="maxPos" 
      select="Math:max($treeWithLayout/*/@tree:WEIGHT * 
                       ($nodeWidth + $horzSpace),
                       $treeWithLayout/*/@tree:MAXDEPTH * 
                         ($nodeHeight + $vertSpace))"/>
...
```

Comment: I was using the default Xalan (obvious from usage of JSTL), but I'm going to back up into the test and will try transforming with Saxon, since I am having quite a few different problems, and Saxon is what is used in the book.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [usage online](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xalanextensions.html):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:math="xalan://java.lang.Math"
  extension-element-prefixes="math">
```

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the math namespace to use "xalan://", and proved that Math does work.  The problem remains that something inside of "Math:max($treeWithLayout/*/@tree:WEIGHT * ($nodeWidth + $horzSpace),$treeWithLayout/*/@tree:MAXDEPTH * ($nodeHeight + $vertSpace))" is causing the problem...

Comment: Thanks...the xalan:// is what I needed.  Although, I soon had to move to Saxon for XSLT 2.0 support.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this message if there is any missing argument. For example:

You write

```
<xsl:variable name="maxPos" select="Math:max(9)"/>
```

instead

```
<xsl:variable name="maxPos" select="Math:max(9, 15)"/>
```